# JPA - ManyToOne breaks when @GenerateValue is not present

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have 2 entities with a relationship of OneToMany

```
@Entity
class Post {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet();

    public void addComment(Comment c) {
        c.setPost(this);
        comments.add(c);
    }
}

@Entity
class Comment {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Post post;
}

CREATE TABLE post(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('post_id_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE comment (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    post_id BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    text VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT fk_comment_post_id
      FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
      REFERENCES post (id)
);
```

When a save this entity everything works fine, and ***savedPost*** is a complete entity that includes the comment.

```
Post post = new Post();
post.setId(1L);
post.setTitle("Hello post test");
post.addComment(new Comment("Hi There");
Post savedPost = postRepository.save(post);
```

But, from the moment I decided to remove that sequence to generate the Post Id in the Post table, and remove the annotation @GenerateValue and set the id with a number generated by me, things start to fall

```
CREATE TABLE post(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(50)
);

@Entity
class Post {    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    ... 
}
```

Now after saving the post the ***savedPost*** object does not contains the comments any more (actually it contains one Comment with all fields null). It seems that the join is broken.

Any idea where and why it is happening?

---

**UPDATE** based on Simon Martinelli's code: github.com/simasch/69978943

If instead of `.save(post)` I call `.saveAndFlush(post)` the comment returns with ONLY its ID set, the rest of the fields come null. It is better than the behavior I describe, but still not good.

But if I annotate `Post.id` with `@GeneratedValue` and use`.save(post)`, everything works perfectly.

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;
```

Comment: How does the table comment look like? Is the FK really id not post_id?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Fk was wrong (my mistake at time to write this question), I fixed it and also put more information about the Comment table.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but for me everything works fine. Checkout my project https://github.com/simasch/69978943

Comment: Hey @SimonMartinelli, thanks for that. I updated my question with extra information I got checking your code. Please take a look

Comment: If you add CascadeType.MERGE then it works! I'm still investigating why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be found in the `SimpleJpaRepository` `save()` method

```
@Transactional
@Override
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null.");

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

There it is checking if the entity is new. But as you set the ID manually it is not considered as new and therefor not `EntityManger.persist()` but `EntityManager.merge()` is called.

So you need to add the CascadeType.MERGE to the mapping

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
           cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Now that you mentioned it sounds like an obvious thing, but it is not and I wouldn't get to this point so easily. Thanks a million!

Comment: It's not that obvious and I'm even not sure if Spring Data JPA handles this correctly